# to_number() returning wrong information

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, greenplum

Using Greenplum on postgres version 8.2:

When I call this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(_date date)
RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
Declare  
_query text;
_date text;
BEGIN
batch_query := 'select to_number('||_date||', ''9999x99x99'')';
EXECUTE _query into _date;
RETURN _date;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

using this call:

```
select test_function('2012-01-15');
```

I'm getting 1996 as the result. I want the result to be 20120115 (which is the date that I input without the dashes)

How am I gett 1996 as a result of this function. When I input other dates I get other random "years" as well. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`to_number()` converts a string into a number (hence the name).

It does **not** know anything about dates.

You are calling the function with a string value, but the function is defined to accept a `date`, thus the string get's converted into a `date` value, and then it gets converted *back* into a string because `to_number()` expects one.

The `to_number()` function then sees: "2012 minus 1 minus 15" - which yields 1996.

If you want to pass a **real** date, then you are looking for the `to_char()` function to format your date.

Additionally you don't need PL/pgSQL for this, nor do you need dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(_date date)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
  select to_char(_date, 'yyyymmdd')';
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

If you want to pass a *string* (`varchar`, `text`) value then you *can* use the `to_number()` function but you need to define the parameter as `text` in order to avoid the evil implicit typecast. But you should also define the function as `returns numeric` because that's what `to_number()` returns. Otherwise you *again* get an implicit data type conversion.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(_date text)
  RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
  select to_number(_date, '9999x99x99')';
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql;
```